# Feedback link doesn't work

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, feedback

Clicking on feedback link at the top of the footer bar of the website (on this and the main SO at least) just links back to the homepage and not to a page for feedback. imo contact us and feedback could come under the same heading/link.

Comment: It's supposed to. Meta is the place where you provide feedback (bugs, feature requests, etc).

Comment: Ah right that makes a lot of sense. Sorry!